# list<A> = list<B> when B inherits from A possible?

Tags: c#

Basically I have

`BallisticProjectile` class which inherits from `Projectile` class. Now I can do this

```
Projectile A;
BallisticProjectile B;

Projectile myfunction()
{
    return B;
}
```

and return B as a projectile.

But I can't do

```
list<Projectile> myfunction()
{
    return B;
}
```

and i'm not sure how to overcome this.

Do I need a wrapper class around it so I have like

```
ProjectileList
{
    list<projectile> Projectiles;
}

BallisticProjectiles : Projectile
{
    list<ballisticprojectile> Projectiles;
}
```

real code (from unity game engine)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
public abstract class Weapon : MonoBehaviour {
    IEnumerable<Projectile> _Projectile;


    public virtual IEnumerable<Projectile> projectile
    {
        get
        {
            return _Projectile;
        }
        set
        {
            _Projectile = value;
        }
    }
}
```

other script

```
public override IEnumerable<BallisticProjectile> projectile {
    get {
        if(_BallisticProjectile == null)
            Debug.Log("ERROR: " + this.gameObject.name + " NO PROJECTILE");

        return _BallisticProjectile;
    }
    set {
        if(value is IEnumerable<BallisticProjectile>)
        {
            _BallisticProjectile = value as IEnumerable<BallisticProjectile>;
            base.projectile = _BallisticProjectile;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you definitely need to return a `List<T>` rather than just an `IEnumerable<T>`? It's also not at all clear why `BallisticProjectiles` would derive from `Projectile`...

Comment: Why not add an `IProjectile` interface that both inherit from and just return `List<IProjectile>`?

Comment: Why not use generics? `ProjectileList<T> where T : Projectile { List<T> Projectiles; }`

Comment: It would be better if you posted the actual code. Not at all clear what you're after.

Comment: added full code to give an idea what im trying to do. Im going to look up interfaces to see how that works. Let me know if if you think i should use interfaces or generics or ienumerable

Comment: SO what I want is to have projectile be a common set of functions and stuff that all projectiles have like Fire() function or perhaps damage value. Then i'll have ballistic projectile but also energy projectile or other types of projectiles inheriting the base projectile stuff. I'm trying to do generics but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @NickGotch They could also instantiate a list of the basetype (if the interface is unnecessary).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `List<BallisticProjectile>` can't be used as a `List<Projectile>`. An easy way to see why is that you could add a `new Projectile()` to a `List<Projectile>`, which doesn't make any sense to have in a `List<BallisticProjectile>`.

This approach lets you set up the projectile type in a generic fashion, and may solve your problem (same as [p.s.w.g](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1715579/p-s-w-g) suggested):

```
public class ProjectileList<T> where T : Projectile
{
    List<T> Projectiles;
}
```

**Update:** in your case, that might look like:

```
public abstract class Weapon<T> : MonoBehaviour where T : Projectile {
    public virtual IList<T> Projectiles { get; set; }
}
```

And then:

```
public class Crossbow : Weapon<BallisticProjectile> {
    // if you needed to override the implementation, you'd start with this:
    // public override IList<BallisticProjectile> Projectiles { get { } set { } }
}
```

The issue here is that C# does not let you change the type of a property (or other member) when you override it. Whether the types are compatible in some way doesn't matter, you must declare it with the same type. Generics is, in this way, a way of making the virtual property change to `BallisticProperty`.

Comment: so how would i use a ballistic projectile in this instance. Sorry i'm just vague on generics and interfaces. I read the MSDN stuff but it seems too technical to really explain it.

Comment: If you want a list of ballistic projectiles, use `ProjectileList<BallisticProjectile>`.

Comment: how do i do inheritance with that. I tried changing my code and i still cant get away from the whole ballistic projectile cant be projectile thing.

Comment: @sparkzbarca I've updated my answer based on the new info you've provided.

Answer (score 1):

In C# 4 you can convert `IEnumerable<B>` to `IEnumerable<A>` if B is inherited from A. It is possible because `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant with T (but `List<T>` is contravariant with T). So may be you can use IEnumerable<> instead of List<>

Comment: i converted my list to ienumerable its still giving me the error. Code added

Comment: `List<T>` is "invariant" in `T`, so neither covariant nor contravariant. In C# 4 (and 5) only interfaces and delegate types may be declared co- or contravariant. Generic classes and structs cannot. `List<>` is a `class`.